# Not able to change the column datatype in the SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list created in the SharePoint Online. In the list I have few lookup columns besides normal ones. I'm trying to change the datatype of a column from Single Line of text to Number or any other datatype. But while changing the datatype from the **List Settings** I'm getting following error

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904

While changing the datatype from the list view itself I'm getting following error

> *Sorry, we couldn't edit the column. Please try again later*

The above errors doesn't seems to be descriptive to find out the actual issue. I've tried to search around but I didn't find any solution.

**Note:** Whenever I go to view the permissions for the list, I get following warning message

> There are limited access users on this site. Users may have limited
> access if an item or document under the site has been shared with them

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check if you have enabled item-level permission on that list. The symptom you mention is quite similar to this blog:https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/error-exception-from-hresult-0x80131904/

Comment: **There are limited access users on this site. Users may have limited access if an item or document under the site has been shared with them** - does this message means that item level permissions are provided ?

Comment: @BBRK, they are different thing. This means that if an item has been shared with a user, but the entire list, library, or survey has not, then their access is limited to the one item that has been shared with them. Click Show users to see who they are.

Comment: I have checked as you have asked me, I found two User group one is **Limited Access System Group** and **MacroView** (Doesn't have any information) group. Can these groups create any problems ?